# По какой причине, оборудование через dll работает в WinForm, а в ASP.NET нет?

Tags: winforms, asp.net

Есть проект локального веб приложения, которое использует сканер. При попытке подключения к оборудованию dll выдает ошибку подключения, т.е. библиотека подключается корректно. Аналогичный код в WinForm работает корректно.

Есть подозрения что дело в настройках IIS сервера. Я прослушал usb порт, при подключении через корректное приложение и при успешном коннекте видно, что никаких данных не отправляется и не принимается, статус - успешно. 
Вот и сам код. Одинаковый как и в WinForms, так и в ASP.NET

```
[DllImport("Dll\\IDC-V\\ScanDll.dll")]
public static extern int IO_HasScanner(string DeviceName, IntPtr Handle);

IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);
API_IDCV.iRet = IO_HasScanner("IDC_V", ptr);
```

Comment: Попробуйте ` thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);`, как написано на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448134/asp-net-and-com-interop

Answer (score 1):

Помогла настройка пула: `Start Mode:AlwaysRunning`